# How to grant network access to LocalSystem account?

Tags: windows, security, authentication, local-system

How do you grant access to network resources to the `LocalSystem` (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) account?

---

### Background

When accessing the network, the LocalSystem account [acts as the computer on the network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190(VS.85).aspx):

> ### LocalSystem Account
>
> The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager.
>
> ...and acts as the computer on the
>   network.

Or to say the same thing again: The LocalSystem account [acts as the computer on the network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677973(VS.85).aspx):

> When a service runs under the
>   LocalSystem account on a computer that
>   is a domain member, the service has
>   whatever network access is granted to
>   the computer account, or to any groups
>   of which the computer account is a
>   member.

How does one grant a "**computer**" access to a shared folder and files?

---

[Note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677973(VS.85).aspx):

> Computer accounts typically have few
>   privileges and do not belong to
>   groups.

So how would i grant a computer access to one of my shares; considering that "**Everyone**" already has access?

**Note**: workgroup

```
| Account        | Presents credentials |
|----------------|----------------------|
| LocalSystem    | Machine$             |
| LocalService   | Anonymous            |
| NetworkService | Machine$             |
```

Comment: This question is slightly related to the earlier [question related to enabling anonymous access to a share](http://serverfault.com/q/51635/191799) - at least it seems it can be solved with an anonymously accessible share.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In a domain environment, you can grant access rights to computer accounts; this applies to processes running on those computers as `LocalSystem` or `NetworkService` (but not `LocalService`, which presents anonymous credentials on the network) when they connect to remote systems.

So, if you have a computer called `MANGO`, that machine will have a *computer* account in Active Directory called `MANGO$`, which you can grant permissions to.

[image]

**Note**: You can't do any of this in a workgroup environment; this applies only to domains.

Comment: +1 and accepted. **But:** LocalService *can* access the network, it just "presents anonymous credentials on the network" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684188(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Just to mention, having spent a not inconsiderable amount of time trying to get this to work for multiple domains I don't think it's possible. i.e. \\DOMAIN2\MANGO$ doesn't appear to grant access.

Comment: This only works if the domains are in a trust relationship; otherwise, you're correct, it doesn't work.

Comment: I thought everyday groups includes authenticated users as well as local_service and local_system account?

Comment: Note that `LocalSystem` can also access anything that any other process can. It can thus steal credentials of logged-on users.

Comment: Related to @IanBoyd 's first comment, granting "Anonymous Logon" permission to a folder still does not allow LOCALSYSTEM to access it. This is relevant, in my case, to attempting to move/migrate Hyper-V VMs from a workgroup host onto a domain-joined host. Hyper-V operations are run as LOCALSYSTEM, which is probably a big part of the reason that live migrations are only supported on a domain.

Answer (score 5):

It's useful to note that computer accounts also fall under Authenticated Users.  So you don't have to grant individual computerName$ accounts on your network resource, you can cover all your computers by granting rights to Authenticated Users, if that's your desired scenario.

You can also use YourDomain\Domain Computers

Comment: The OP was a workgroup, so this won't work for the question as asked.

Comment: On the other hand, [stackexchange is a combination of Wikipedia meets reddit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/), and this is [useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371355/12597) information to have on this wiki entry.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. If you need a service to connect to remote files or other network services, then you want to have the service run as a named account, and on the remote machine, assign rights to that named account.

It would really be best if you full explain what you're trying to do - that way you'll get the best answers.

Comment: Totally incorrect. You can grant permissions to machine accounts (and thus to services running as them) exactly the same way you can grant them to user accounts. There are of course scenarios where this might not be the best solution, but it's perfectly doable.

Comment: @Massimo: mfinni is not saying that you can't technically do it, but that you dont want to do it--It is best practice to run the service as a named account.

Comment: The answer looked exactly like that, this is the reason for my downvote; also, the original poster seem to know quite well the difference between an user account and a computer one, so answering his question with "don't do that" just didn't seem right to me.

Comment: Also, downvoting *my* answer (which **is** technically correct, as opposed to mfinni's one) is not exactly fair.

Comment: Besides, there are very legitimate scenarios where granting permissions to machine accounts would be needed. Just think about computer startup scripts, or GPO software deployment, or services which just want to run as LocalSystem and you can't do anything about that. I'm not saying this is a best practice or "the" right solution, of course; but if someone asks "how to do this?" I think "don't do it" is definitely not a correct answer.

Comment: Massimo - the OP specified that this is a workgroup, so there is no domain. Thus, RemoteServer A wouldn't know the difference between the machine account for Machine B and Machine BadGuy. You're right, that my answer was not technically correct, but I think that it was the best answer for what we know from the OP.

Comment: In a workgroup environment, you can't assign rights on MachineB to an user account defined on MachineA... besides, he was asked specifically how to assign rights to a *maschine* account, so that's what I answered to; and I also said that this was not possible without a domain.

Comment: What i was trying to do is grant **SQL Server**, running as `LocalSystem`, access to a network share; and to do so without **a)** stopping the SQL Server service, **b)** creating a new account for SQL Server to login as, or **c)** changing what account SQL Server logs in as.  Also, my reasons for asking the question are irrelevant. i phrased the question so people besides me could use the knowledge and apply it to their individual situations. Finally, while i am in this particular instance on a domain: any complete answer would include instructions for on a workgroup.

Comment: Massimo - if he's in a workgroup, he can make an account with an identical username and password on both machines, that will work as I described.

Comment: Ian - if that's what you're after, it's usually a better idea to use the SQL Server Agent and its account, or use Integration Services. You can get more detail when you ask a detailed question, and it can still be very applicable to other readers' situations.

Answer (score -1):

**It is Simple:**

Put the Machine´s AD Account into the local Admins Group
and then this Machine (or its Local Admin Account)
can fully Access the destination OVER the Network.
Tested today, works fine.

Comment: While this is functional, it is NOT recommended or best practice. The `Local System` account is called local for a reason. If you want something to have network access, the service or otherwise should be changed to run as another user. This would be like granting the `guest` account on a machine administrator access. It would work, but that defeats the purpose of what it was built for.