# Shared folder are inaccessible from system account

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-7

I have problem with different behavior of network machines. Little log:

```
C:\Windows\system32>whoami
nt authority\system

C:\Windows\system32>net view
Server Name            Remark
------------------------------------------
\\02210585DS001
\\02210585SS001
\\02210585SS002
\\02210585WS001
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>net view 02210585SS001
Shared resources at 02210585SS001

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment
------------------------------------------
APPLDRV     Disk  (UNC)
BKUPDRV     Disk
DATADRV     Disk
SYSTDRV     Disk
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>net view 02210585WS001
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Could you tell me where I should search the reason of this? I couldn't find any differences in configuration of this machines.

**Added:** Sorry for long response. Share and NTFS ACLs:

System that works correctly:

```
C:\>icacls c:
c: BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(AD)
   Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


C:\>rmtshare \\02210585SS001\DATADRV
Share name        \\02210585SS001\DATADRV
Path              C:\
Remark
Maximum users     No limit
Users             1
Permissions:
        \Everyone  :  FULL CONTROL
 BUILTIN\Users     :  CHANGE
 BUILTIN\Administrators:  CHANGE
The command completed successfully.
```

System that didn't works:

```
C:\>icacls c:
c: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(S,AD)
   Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


C:\>rmtshare \\02210585WS001\DATADRV
Share name        \\02210585WS001\DATADRV
Path              C:\
Remark
Maximum users     No limit
Users             0
Permissions:
        \Everyone  :  FULL CONTROL
 BUILTIN\Administrators:  CHANGE
 BUILTIN\Users     :  CHANGE
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: List the share and NTFS ACLs from the server that works and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Is there a difference in membership of the local Administrators group between 02210585SS001 and 02210585WS001? `net view` is going to require local admin rights on the destination server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disturbing... 
There was one command in windows startup scripts with net use of 02210585SS001 shared folder. So this is the reason of this.

Answer (score 0):

You're logged in as NT AUTHORITY\System, which means that you appear to the network as the computer account (as per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/howt-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account)).

My guess is that your computer account is a member of one of your local groups on SS001 but not on WS001?